# svg, color group child elements

Tags: javascript, css, svg

I created a SVG out of illustrator.  The elements have the fill on the paths.  I am trying to change the color based on the group id that the path is in.

I would like to change all child elements fill colors in the same group to the same color when an event happens.

Here is a jsFiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/cdcgbu6g/6/

```
function ChangeColor(zone,color,colorCode) {
document.getElementById(zone).children().css( "fill", colorCode );
};
```

The javascript would be in an external .js file.

When you click a color square, the fill value on the two objects should change that are under the group id of "Color_1".

Everything I read says this should work.

Comment: What is the question?

Comment: @Kaiido I simplified and hopefully clarified the question.  Trying to change the fill on all child elements in a specific group when a color square is clicked.  Thank you.

Comment: It's not really clarified to me since your code does work. What is the expected behaviour that you don't have here ? (In your last fiddle you are trying to use jQuery `children()` method on a non jQuery Object. check this update : http://jsfiddle.net/cdcgbu6g/8/)

Comment: @Kaiido This is what I was looking for.  If you make it an Answer I will accept it.  Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As stated by [@Paul LeBeau](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30770425/3702797) your first snippet did work well, just a jsFiddle configuration issue.

However, while revising your post, you brought a new error :

```
function ChangeColor(zone,color,colorCode) {
   document.getElementById(zone).children().css( "fill", colorCode );
};
```

**This code won't work** because you are trying to call jQuery methods (`.children()` and `.css()`) on a non jQuery object (`document.getElementById()` does return a DOM object ).

You could rewrite this function to :

```
function ChangeColor(zone,color,colorCode) {
  $('#'+zone).children().css( "fill", colorCode );
};
```

Now we're calling a jQuery object and everything works well, just like in your first snippet where you weren't using jQuery.

Answer (score 0):

Your fiddle works fine if you change when the Javascript gets run.  If you change it to one of the `No wrap` options, all is well.

http://jsfiddle.net/cdcgbu6g/4/

**Update: why is this?**

I haven't looked at what exactly jsfiddle is doing, but I imagine that it works something like the following:

When you use the "onLoad" option, it is doing something equivalent to the following:

```
window.onload = function() {
   // users fiddle JS here
};
```

That means that any functions you define (ie. `ChangeColor()`) will be defined inside the ready function's namespace and won't be visible to the HTML event handlers.

There are two alternatives solutions.  Change the run mode to one of the two "No wrap" options as I suggested above.

Alternatively you could stay with "onLoad" mode and force the function into the global namespace (window), or another namespce under that.

```
window.ChangeColor = function(zone,color,colorCode) {
    document.getElementById(zone).style.fill = colorCode;
};
```

http://jsfiddle.net/cdcgbu6g/7/

Comment: Which leads to […](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30767314/svg-color-group-child-elements#comment49590716_30767314)

Comment: What is the difference in OnLoad vs no wrap - body.  Is it running the javascript when the document is loaded with OnLoad.  I am new to fiddle so just learning.